# How to uninstall a Web Platform Installer (WPI) application?

Tags: uninstallation, web-platform-installer

I have looked all around the internet, and can't seem to figure out how to uninstall a WPI application. I accidentally installed something thinking it was something else, and now I can't uninstall it.

Answer (score 6):

You could remove them via control panel.
Depending on what you want to remove, you either need to:
Go into windows programs and features and turn windows features on/off, locate the feature you wish to remove and untick it.
Else
Go to uninstall a program section and locate it that way and uninstall as you would any other program.

Comment: Neither this nor the 'Uninstall or change a program' panel seem to have a list of WPI apps. Here's a good rundown: http://superuser.com/questions/482801/how-can-i-uninstall-a-component-that-was-installed-by-web-platform-installer

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to know and solved my issue. .

Comment: WPI components don't show up in Control Panel (at least none I've used)

Answer (score 4):

I achieved this by opening IIS Manager selecting Handler Mappings (From the root node). I then deleted all PHP Handlers, I then opened FastCGI settings and deleted all php settings. I then removed all php entires from the system path and finally used those paths to know where PHP was installed and deleted the php folders. Finally The web platform installer allowed me to reinstall PHP and re-setup the handlers mappings for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Server Manager to do that.

1. Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Server Manager
2. Highlight Roles in tree view on left
3. Under Web Server (IIS) section, look to right and click "Remove Role Services"
4. Then uncheck the role you want to remove

This usually requires you to reboot the server after removal.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am not familiar with IIS on a consumer grade operating system, but maybe try installing IIS Management Console (Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off; expand IIS -> Web Management Tools).

Comment: Well what did it install, maybe it isn't called Server Manager and whatever it installed provides that same functionality.

Comment: For Windows7 (Professional) it is Computer Management, but there is no roles. The IIS is under Services and Application but since there are no roles I think we can't uninstall the WebPI application on this way. I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If anything didn't work.. you can try install windows install clean up tool. Few clicks to get rid from that WPI

Cheers