# How do I uninstall python from web platform installer?

Tags: python, web-platform-installer

I've installed python and some other packages using web platform installer, but I was having some issues getting a Django project to work so I uninstalled everything and am trying to get it going from scratch. Web Platform Installer still shows that I have 'Windows Azure SDK for Python" and "Python 2.7 (32-bit)" installed however and I can't mark them as uninstalled.

I don't see where to uninstall from WPI at all, I uninstalled them using control panel. I think I had originally installed python from the python site and had version 3.3 and 2.7 (64-bit), but now there are no entries containing 'python' when I try to uninstall a program from the control panel.

Does anyone know what is going on or can I download the setups from somewhere and try them manually? Is there a way to reset what shows as installed in WPI? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling WPI but that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930823/how-to-uninstall-a-web-platform-installer-wpi-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a PowerShell script in the WPI directory that checked for python installs and I had to delete the registry keys specified in it.

---

Let me add some context:

Open the below path,

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PythonDetectInstalls
```

in the sub-folder of the above path, there is a PowerShell script "DetectPythonInstalls.ps1" which contains two script lines for checking if Python is installed:

```
$regKey = "hklm:SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\$pythonVersion\InstallPath";
$correctRegKey = "hklm:SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\$pythonVersion\InstallPath";
```

Uninstall all Python versions you do not neet. However, we need to remove some registry keys manually using "regedit".

(Safety Note: Please take a backup of the registry keys before removing the above-mentioned registry key)

Ref: [Social.Tecnet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee1d9598-d683-441a-9e26-2cd0b45730c9/uninstall-an-application-installed-with-web-platform-installer-50?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I just deleted the folder containing the installed PHP versions(5.3,5.4,5.5), which for me was \Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP.  Also, I removed "\Program Files (x86)\iis express\php\5.3" from the search path.

When I return to the web installer the 'Add' buttons are enabled.

I opened the options, set the Web Server to IIS, then installed PHP v5.5.  It was installed into \Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5 and added to the search path.

Answer (score 0):

This is how IIS recommends doing it:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1178803.aspx

Open `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config` file and 
1. Find following entry (or similar entry) in applicationhost.config file and comment it or delete it.

1. Find following entry in hanlders section and comment this as well or delete.

3.By default Web Platform Installer installs PHP to `%programfiles%\iis express\php\`. so open `%programfiles%\iis express\php\` folder and delete the php version folder that you no longer need (don't forget to remove relavant entries from applicationhost.config as mentioned in step 1 and 2 above)

Of course you would need to find the python one instead of php but it is the jist of it

Comment: That's php, I don't see that directory or any for python.  The applicationhost.config does not contain the string 'python' either.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Sorry, I don't know how to help besides going to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off; expand IIS -> Web Management Tools, and installing management console to uninstall python.

Comment: I don't think it is actually tied to IIS at all, it's just python and the azure sdk for python which is more visual studio I believe

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't help you.